# Laravel- How to select randomly

Tags: laravel

I have a data i collected but not in the database

`$name = "michael, esther, peace";`

How do i pick this names randomly on laravel

I have no idea on how to do that. Please help

Comment: explode to array, collect that array and call the `random()` function on that array

Comment: can you help me with any document on that

Comment: [PHP Explode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and [Laravel collect](https://laravel.com/docs/collections#creating-collections) and [random](https://laravel.com/docs/collections#method-random)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `explode` first since `collect` requires array to continue.

```php
$names = collect(explode(',', 'michael, esther, peace'));

$names->random();
```

Comment: it is returning the all the values

Comment: You can pass `$names->random(3)` if you wish to return them all